# android.media.Ringtone.play() stops working after a 28 plays

Tags: android, ringtone, ringtonemanager

I have an app that is open for hours and uses a background service with foreground notification attached to it. Every once in a while a sound is played using:

```
try {
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);
    r.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The sounds are working, but **after a while the sounds don't play anymore.**
No errors, no warnings, no crashes. Just no sound.

My users are complaining as well, so it doesn't look like a device specific issue.

[Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html) don't mention anything about this.
Anyone knows why this is?

Comment: Have you tried using MediaPlayer instead of Ringtone?
Something like here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832634/android-mediaplayer-play-ringtone-one-time

Comment: Yes I have, see my answer for my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't create a Ringtone or MediaPlayer in a BroadcastReceiver!**

The problem was the context of the Ringtone or MediaPlayer. By triggering the sound form a broadcast receiver a new MediaPlayer or Ringtone was created every time the sound played. After 28 times, the sound just didn't play anymore.

By playing the sound from an IntentSerice, or re-useing a static instance of the MediaPlayer or Ringtone, everything played as expected.